# Sending CDATA over Axis RPC client

Tags: java, axis, rpc, cdata

Can anyone let me know how to send CDATA over Axis (old version, not Axis2) RPC client in Java?

I tried to find the answer for this in lots of places but couldn't get any clear answer at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
String stringToBeWrapped = "A'B'C'D";
OMElement elementWhichNeedsCData = ....;
TextImpl omText = (TextImpl)
bodyElement.getOMFactory().createOMText(stringToBeWrapped);
omText.setType(XMLStreamConstants.CDATA);
elementWhichNeedsCData.addChild(omText);
```

from http://axis.8716.n7.nabble.com/Problem-with-CDATA-tags-in-SOAP-message-td39617.html